# Add forge viewer measurement tool for Point Cloud

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have added Point-Cloud to forge viewer. I have created extension for the same and it works good.

As an advancement, I want to add Forge Viewer's Measurement tool for Point Cloud to measure distance between two points like Potree.
But as I observed, we can use Forge Viewer's measurement tool to measure on model faces only, I don't know whether my observation is correct or not.

I want to measure the distance between points which are outside the model's face ([refer this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smjt9.png)). In the image, the coloured portion is my Point Cloud flying between two faces of model.
I want to give option to user so that they can measure distance between the points from Point-Cloud.

Is there any option in forge viewer to do this??

OR

Do I need to use any shader to serve points as faces?

OR

Is there any limitation in forge viewer like measurement tool can be used with objects those are added by forge viewer itself??

Thanks.

Comment: May I know what kind is the Point-Cloud you mentioned? As I know, Point-Cloud translation is not available on Forge currently. Or, is it `THREE.PointCloud`?

Comment: Yes, it is `THREE.PointCloud` .
I am adding it into `GuiViewer3d.impl.scene` .

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, most of viewer features are made for Forge translated geometries loaded via ‘Viewer3D#loadModel’. Since the point cloud you mentioned is archived by THREE.PointCloud, it’s not parts of Forge translated model(i.e. custom geometries), the measurement extension won’t works for your case.

Comment: Thanks @Eason.
Is there any other way to do this? like add my custom geometry to forge translated geometry.

Comment: No, you cannot add custom geometries into Forge managed one. The Forge managed geometries have a complex data structure. But you can implement a "Tool" to access callbacks of the Viewer canvas such as mouse events, keyboard events, touch events and etc. to create your own measurement. https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/03/creating-tools-for-the-view-data-api.html

Comment: For the measurement part, maybe check this blog from my colleague: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/area-planning-tool-forge-viewer-and-mysql . He created an area planning tool from a custom measure tool.